# Advantages of using NSUserDefaults to save game settings/state?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Is there any benefit in going with NSUserDefaults to save game state/settings over creating a binary file in plain C?

Specifically for an iOS game.

Answer (score 5):

The biggest advantage with NSUserDefaults is that you don't have to worry about the actual writing to "disk" — `-synchronize` is automatically called at "appropriate times", which includes app background (if multitasking is supported) or termination (if multitasking is not supported, or you set UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend or whatever it's called). This means you can update NSUserDefaults much more frequently without as much overhead.

The disadvantage is that I'm pretty sure the whole thing is loaded into memory and a write involves writing the whole file (I think it even writes to a temporary file and then does a rename), so it's not suitable for storing large, infrequently-changing blobs (e.g. photos).

Unless your saved games are huge, I'd do something reasinably simple with NSUserDefaults, mostly because it avoids you having to keep track of a bunch of files.

**EDIT:** A potentially major drawback with NSUserDefaults is that doesn't save when the app crashes, so you might still want to explicitly `-synchronize` occasionally, depending on how crashy your app is. This is particularly noticable for developers, since pressing "stop" in Xcode (or unplugging the phone while debugging) is effectively a crash!

Answer (score 1):

`NSUserDefaults` is the appropriate location for settings, but probably not save games.

The advantage is you get in-memory caching and several decades of stability behind it. The downside is you are fairly limited in what you can put in a user defaults file (objects must be `plist`-friendly, i.e. strings, numbers, data, dates, dictionaries, and arrays only.) As well, saving game state in `NSUserDefaults` would make it more difficult to handle multiple save games.

I would recommend you build your logic classes such that they can be serialized/deserialized to/from an arbitrary byte stream (easiest way to do that is to implement `NSCoding` on your various game state classes.) Then you can just dump files to disk to arbitrary locations (e.g. a "quicksave" copy in `NSUserDefaults` and a list of full savegames in `[yourapp]/Documents/`. The task of encoding/decoding is not actually strongly associated with the task of storage/retrieval, as surprising as that might be.

Comment: I'd actually avoid the Documents directory, as this can be accessed by the user if you set `<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key><true/>` in Info.plist. And if you're going to serialize an NSCoding-conforming object with NSKeyedArchiver, you can put the resulting NSData in NSUserDefaults anyway. While it may not be "appropriate", it's certainly easy. (You can even handle multiple saved dames by sticking an array in NSUserDefaults, though it's not very efficient!)

Comment: 1) Aware of the `UIFileSharingEnabled` key. That was just an example, and besides, there may be value in allowing the user to back up savegames. 2) Also aware that you can use `NSCoder` objects to turn arbitrary data into plist-friendly `NSData` objects. That was part of my point, actually. :)

Comment: Depending on your game, you may not want to make it easy for users to load arbitrary saved games (i.e. cheat!), especially if you have high scores. Of course, this is still pretty easy to do by editing the iPhone backup, but the barrier is *slightly* higher.

Comment: True; for many games you don't want that ability. But for other games, it's a useful feature. This is rather outside the scope of the original question, though. :)